# google maps distance matrix

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-maps

I am using the Google Distance Matrix to determine the distance between the user and our centres.

This works fine, however the documentation states:

"Use of the Distance Matrix API must relate to the display of information on a Google Map; for example, to determine origin-destination pairs that fall within a specific driving time from one another, before requesting and displaying those destinations on a map. Use of the service in an application that doesn't display a Google map is prohibited."

But I am unsure how to "request and display the destinations on a map"

Is it possible to show the map in my application with the directions? If so where do I start? I have been looking but have been unsuccessful so must be searching for the wrong thing.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2012

ASPX.NET Application (VB)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the google maps Image API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/

Comment: I didn't really want a static map, i wanted something like what can be seen here https://developers.google.com/maps/location-based-apps (Get your users from A to B), I have the distance and travel time sorted but cannot figure out how to implement a map the way they have that shows the actual route and can switch between the alternatives (does not need to be on hover, but you get the idea)

Comment: Google_maps API and Google_Places API are poweful API's.Try reading the documentation and I hope u can get the desired results

Comment: is it possible to get travel distance or driving distace dynamically?

Comment: Yes that is possible..You can refer to this documentation from google     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/